# WCF NetTcpPortSharing only works for localhost?

Tags: .net, wcf, windows-server-2008-r2

I have a WCF service that's been working for a long time with an endpoint address on localhost.

**Works:** `net.tcp://localhost/myApp`

**Fails:** `net.tcp://100.5.5.5/myApp`

I want to expose the service to another box on the network.  The failing version throws the following error:

`The TransportManager failed to listen on the supplied URI using the NetTcpPortSharing service:  the service failed to listen.`

What is it about switching from localhost to an IP that flummoxed WCF?

Comment: Is the "Net.Tcp Port Sharing Service" installed and running on the machine. How is the service hosted IIS or self-hosted ?

Comment: Can you try a different port number,maybe the default port 808 is already in use. Also thee may be some security/firewall issues that is blocking the port. Is the account the service running a local administrator ? otherwise give the account local admin privilege and try.

Answer (score 0):

You have to listen on an IP that's assigned to the host.  Doh!